# How to pass selection box and text value from searching form to controller using ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, parameter-passing

I make a search filter by filtering states, categories, levels and age. User will select the value using select boxes and text field. Once user click the button, ajax will send the information to controller to be filtered. The code for the form is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::label('negeri_lahir_peg', 'Negeri Lahir Pegawai') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::select('negeri_lahir', $negeri, '', ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'placeholder' => '--pilih--']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="kategori">Kategori:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3"> 
                <select name="kategori" class="form-control select2" style="width:250px">
                    <option value="">-- pilih --</option>
                    @foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="pang">Pangkat:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3"> 
                <select name="pangkat" class="form-control select2"style="width:250px">
                <option>-- pilih --</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2"> 
                {{ Form::label('umur_peg', 'Umur') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1"> 
                {{ Form::text('umur', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3"> 
                {{ Form::label('tahun', 'tahun ke atas') }}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The button for submitting the value to ajax is:

```
 <button id="cari" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Cari </button>
```

I had tried to filter negeri_lahir only in ajax code below but the 'negeri_lahir is undefined' appear in the debugger mode.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#cari" ).click(function() {

      var negeri = $("#negeri_lahir").val();
       $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('calon') }}',
          data: 'negeri_lahir=' + negeri ,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              $('#datatable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
              var html = '';
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                  html += '<tr>'+
                              '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>' +
                          '</tr>';
                  }   
              $('#datatable tr').first().after(html);
          },
          error: function (data) {
          }
      });
  });

</script>
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
  $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
    // ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.categoryid', '=','categories.categoryid')
    // ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.operasiid', '=', 'operasi.operasiid')
    ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan');

    if(request('umur')) {
        $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('umur')]);  
    }

    if(request('negeri_lahir')) {
        $query->where('NegeriID', request('negeri_lahir'));
    }

    if(request('kategori')) {
        $query->where('CategoryID', request('kategori'));
    }

    if(request('pangkat')) {
        $query->where('OperasiID', request('pangkat'));
    }

$newitem = $query->get();
// dd($newitem);
return response::json($newitem);
```

How to pass the value of filter by users to ajax correctly so that it can be processed by controller? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made mistakes in two places.

1. When passing the data in ajax function
2. The way you accessed it in the Controller.

Use following fixes.

Import the following library to your controller,
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

And then in the Controller function,

```
function someName(Request $request){
    $request->input('negeri_lahir');
}
```

In your JS code, pass it as follows:

```
data: {'negeri_lahir': negeri} ,
```

Hope this helps.